# Old heroic fantasy cartoon

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I am looking for an old fantasy cartoon, most probably from the 90s. There were  about 15 human heroes in it.

One was a Jewish king who had a weapon which he swung above his head and threw rocks from. I remember an episode where he or another character said how he fought off a few cyclops.

One hero was definitely a female warrior.

The heroes fought a reptilian king with black eyes and sharp black nails, possibly green skin and purple clothing. He was their main enemy.

There were episodes where the heroes participated in some kind of a fighting event held by the reptilian king. The heroes fought in an arena against snake-headed humanoids with green skin, every one of them were armed with 2 scimitars, they wore purple armor on their chests and had long necks. There were also some other animal-headed humanoids but I don't remember them very well.

Comment: Was this "jewish king" explicitly noted to be Jewish? Or was there something about his appearance that made you think he was?

Comment: He said that he's jewish himself & told a story how he helped his Kingdom & fought villains there before joining those other guys.

Comment: This question could maybe use revisiting. Any other details you can remember? When did you see it, in what country, what language, was it an after school cartoon or a Saturday morning cartoon, any and all details are relevant and may be the key to unlocking this. The Jewish king angle seems pretty clearly to be King David, which would seem to be easy to locate, but there are plenty of bible story cartoons that overwhelm the results.

Answer (score 4):

For a 90s cartoon, two possibilities come two mind...

1. **Conan, the Adventurer,** which was based on the popular character. He had a team of 5 companions, but they fought literal "Serpent men" sent by the wizard Wrath Amon....

[image]

Their eyes weren't black, but they looked like this:
[image]

Another possibility is **King Arthur and the Knights of Justice.** When the evil witch Morgana captures the true King Arthur, a modern day college Football team is brought back to the past by Merlin to take their place, lead by their quarterback Arthur King. There are at least 10 distinct heroes with unique weaponry in this series.

[image]

They have to face off against Morgana's animated stone warriors, including their ruthless leader, Lord Viper, seen here, who was snake themed and dressed in green:
[image]

[image]

Both shows came out in 1992.

Comment: Could you split this into two answers so it's clear what the voting is on and what the answer is should the OP accept without commenting?

Comment: These are only possibilities, though. I thought it prudent to give the OP a visual choice, so that he could more clearly choose one before accepting. Possibility stands, though, that it could be neither of these.

Comment: Well of course they are only possibilities but when it comes to voting and accepting it is better to post it as two answers. There's no real negatives in doing so but a lot to gain from it. _"I thought it prudent to give the OP a visual choice, so that he could more clearly choose one before accepting."_ - this works just as well, perhaps even better, when posting as two answers and also makes things in the long run easier.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a cartoon, but this kind of matches up to *[The Mystic Knights of Tir Na Nog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystic_Knights_of_Tir_Na_Nog)*, a series that aired in 1998.

> Queen Maeve of Temra, to conquer the peaceful kingdom of Kells, enlists the fairy Mider, who gives her the mystical Rune Stone allowing Maeve to use sorcery, most often to create ogres and evil giants, whom she sends to wreak havoc. When King Conchobar of Kells seeks a way to protect his kingdom, protagonist Rohan, a druid's apprentice, goes in search of the prophesized hero 'Draganta', with his friend the reformed thief Angus. Later joined by the foreign Prince Ivar, and Conchobar's daughter, Princess Deirdre, they are drawn into Tir Na Nóg, whose king Fin Varra puts the group through various tests to determine their worthiness. The heroes having passed these tests, King Fin Varra gives them certain weapons granting control of the Classical Elements Fire, Air, Earth, and Water. Thereafter the four overcome Mider's 'Evil Sentinels' (recurring villains in the series) to capture corresponding suits of armor, and oppose the various monsters created by Maeve, assisted by the winged fairy 'Aideen'. Subsequently, Rohan gains a new partner in Pyre the dragon, who later identifies Rohan as Draganta. Later in the series, another Mystic Knight emerges in Prince Garrett of Rheged, who joins the others after they free him from Maeve's telepathic control. With her powers nearly exhausted, Queen Maeve summons the monster 'Lugad', who is more powerful than any previous creation; but he and Rohan are both identified as Maeve's abandoned sons. In the series finale, they co-operate with the other Mystic Knights to defeat Maeve, whom Rohan banishes from both kingdoms.

The guy with the mace is Angus.

> **Angus** – Angus is Rohan's best friend and a well-known, boastful reformed thief who often gets into trouble. His weapon is the Terra Sling Mace which throws giant boulders and can cause earthquakes. To obtain his silver and gold Mystic Armor, he had to defeat the Rock Wolf of Temra. To don his armor, he shouts "Earth beneath me!".

Deirdre is likely the female warrior.

> **Deirdre** – The princess of Kells. Her weapon is the Whirlwind Crossbow, which shoots a burst of air. To win her white and gold Mystic Armor, she had to defeat the Lightning Bat of Temra. To don her armor, she shouts "Air above me!". Deirdre is the most logical-minded of the Mystic Knights, and is therefore sometimes frustrated by her companions' foibles.

I've found reference to them fighting cyclopes

Comment: The best thing about this show was the action figures, and I sorely regret ever selling mine.

Comment: Thanks but no I'm 100% sure it's a cartoon. It's animation sort of reminds of Dragonflyz's animation.